# Replacing Special Symbols in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

Can anyone help me to remove extra characters from the dataframe column? Should I have to use `replace` string method?

For example,

```
`$7.99` -> `7.99`
`$16.99` -> `16.99`
`$0.99` -> `0.99`
```

Comment: `df['col'] = df['col'].str.lstrip('$')`

Comment: you might want to add `.astype(float)`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC: consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['$7.99', '$3.45', '$56.99'])
```

you can use `replace` to do:

```
df[0].str.replace('$', '', regex=False)
```

Output:

```
0     7.99
1     3.45
2    56.99
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Did you mean `regex=False`?

Comment: Works both ways, but yes `regex=False` was intended

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first character with `.str[1:]`:

```py
df["Column1"] = df["Column1"].str[1:].astype(float)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Column1
0     7.99
1    16.99
2     0.99
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
  Column1
0   $7.99
1  $16.99
2   $0.99
```